# Default constructor of a class containing value and its limits as data members

Tags: c++, constructor, limit

Suppose I have a class `Quantity` that contains different data members including `value` and `limits`:

```
class Quantity
{
    protected :
        double value;
        double lower_limit;
        double upper_limit;

    public :
        Quantity();//I need a default constructor
        Quantity( double value, double lower_limit, double upper_limit );
        //function members
        void SetValue( double value );
        void SetLimits( double lower_limit, double upper_limit );
};
```

The problem appears when I try to define default constructor: `value` must lie between the limits. On the other hand, I cannot just initialize `value` and `limits` with some random valid set of numbers because of having set-functions which contain check conditions in their bodies.

Why do I need a default constructor. It is because there is another class (say `Event`) that contains `Quantity` object as a data member:

```
class Event
{
     protected:
         Quantity q1;
         Quantity q2;

     public:
         Event ();//Here it would be an error if I explicitly not initialized members without a default constructor
         ...
};
```

Eventually I want to use it in the following way:

```
//Firstly, declare all objects
Event event;
Quantity q1;
Quantity q2;
//some code which e.g. calculates limits and values
q1.SetLimits(limit1, limit2);
q2.SetValue(value);
event.AddQuantity(q1);
event.AddQuantity(q2);
```

So I define default constructor in this way (other constructor is similar):

```
Quantity::Quantity() : value(0.)
{
    lower_limit = std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest();
    upper_limit = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
}
```

When `SetValue` function looks like (`SetLimits` is similar):

```
Quantity::SetValue( double value )
{
    if ( value between limits )
    {
        this->value = value;
    }
    else
    {
        //do something e.g. throw an exception
    }
}
```

I do not know if the above definition is a correct way to reach what I want (not speaking if it is the elegant one).
So how should one define default constructor i.e. how to initialize `value` and `limits`?

Comment: Why do you "need a default constructor"? How is the class used to make it "need" a default constructor?

Comment: If you do not provide one, a default constructor will be generated by the compiler for you. Unless you need to do something cleaver inside the default constructor - i would suggest leaving it to the compiler

Comment: Seems to be a design flaw. Why first having a default constructor and after it a SetValue method and obscure range checking... You should tell something about your real requirements. What I see here is hopefully not the solution for it ;)

Comment: Why can't you rearrange your code so you calculate limits, value etc. first and then construct `q1` and `q2`? That way you don't need a default constructor.

Comment: Because I want to have all declarations at the beginning of my code.

Comment: Well, that is one of the silliest reasons I've heard for creating a hobbled interface. Declare your variables when you need them, not all bunched together at the beginning of the function.

Comment: @Praetorian, May be I did not understand you. But I think that declaring of variables right before using it is making code messy. Could you explain in detail what you meant?

Comment: "But I think that declaring of variables right before using it is making code messy" Nonsense. It is indeed a very good practice to declare variables as late as possible, e.g. right before their first use.

Comment: unless you have a function of hundreds of lines of code, in which case you have bigger problems and neither option of declaring variables (all at the beginning or before the first use) will not matter.